# What's the equivalent of str.gsub(/^\p{Word}/i, '') in Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby

What's the equivalent of

```
str.gsub(/[^\p{Word} ]/i, '') # works in 1.9.2+
```

in Ruby 1.8.7?

I tried

```
str.gsub(/[^\w\s]/iu, '')
```

But the output includes wider range of characters i.e. ®.

---

An example:

Ruby 2.1.5

```
ruby -e "puts 'abcȣ的®Ȍ'.gsub(/[^\p{Word} ]/i, '')"
#or
#ruby -e "puts \"abc\u0223\u7684\u00ae\u020c\".gsub(/[^\p{Word} ]/i, '')"
```

Output:

```
abcȣ的Ȍ
```

Ruby 1.8.7-p374

```
ruby -e "puts 'abcȣ的®Ȍ'.gsub(/[^\w\s]/iu, '')"
```

Output:

```
abcȣ的®Ȍ
```

Note that in my attempt with Ruby 1.8.7, ® is in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've reopened the question.

Comment: `str.gsub(/^[\w\s]/i, '')` If this does not work please provide some inputs and results

Comment: Thanks Ismael. Without /u, \w only matches ASCII chracters. Replace /iu with /i in my above 1.8.7 example, it only outputs 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up `\p{Word}` in the [regex docs on unicode properties](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties). You'll see it's a combination of the following properties:

- `\p{L}` Letter,
- `\p{M}` Mark,
- `\p{N}` Number, and
- `\p{Pc}` Connector_Punctuation

You can look these up in the [unicode character database](http://unicode.org/ucd/) to determine what codepoints specifically to include in your regex.

Comment: Thanks for the \p{Word} explanation. I'll try it.